# Why did Araki change the power system in JoJo's?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

The original power system in JoJo's was 'Hamon' or the 'Ripple', which utilizes controlled breathing so the user can fill their body and attacks with sunlight energy. Making it very effective against Vampires, Zombies, and Pillar Men.

After part 2, Hamon was just disregarded and then 'Stands' became the new system. I'm not saying that Stands aren't cool, but it just seems like a waste to completely forget Hamon so why did Araki change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stands have so many more possibilities than Hamon. Each individual stand has unique abilities, effects, and strengths. Basically, every user's stand is different. Hamon, on the other hand, is effectively the same for every Hamon user. The only thing that differs is how you use it: for example, Joseph had a different fighting style to Jonathan, but a lot of their fights were still very similar because they both possessed the exact same power. JoJo would have gotten stale and boring to read very quickly had Araki not switched to stands around part 3 - especially when you look at how long the manga has been running.

Comment: Fair enough to that. But I don't see why Hamon was just forgotten.

Comment: Where do you think it could've been used, might I ask? Most of the stand users were strong enough to defeat Hamon should it have been used. And I don't agree that it was forgotten, it was definitely used a number of times in part 3, but only when it made sense to.